# Apache2 mod autoindex does not read .php

Tags: php, apache2, mod-autoindex

Apache2's mod *autoindex* allows to include a header and a readme files, that I configured this way in the directory's `.htaccess`:

```
ReadMeName footer.html
HeaderName header.php
```

For some obscure reason, the header file is not read if it is a `.php`. I renamed it to header.html and in the htaccess too:

```
HeaderName header.html
```

and it worked perfectly (even when in `.html` it included `<?php ?>` markups)

Why does apache do hat, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you read this? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername

Comment: Will do, let me spin it myself first.

Comment: well actually it didn't work... I deleted my comment so you wouldn't see it then but too late apparently ^^

Comment: I even `chmod +x`'d my php and set XBitHack to on but it changed nothing...

Comment: LMAO I got it working. Was worth a lucky shot! :D

Answer (score 0):

Per the manual on [mod_autoindex / HeaderName directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername):

> Filename must resolve to a document with a major content type of
>   text/* (e.g., text/html, text/plain, etc.). This means that filename
>   may refer to a CGI script if the script's actual file type (as opposed
>   to its output) is marked as text/html...

...while a `.php` file's content-type is defined as `application/x-httpd-php`, even if the script's output is by default `text/html`. However, there's hope yet. You can actually get the PHP parsed by adding the following combo into your `.htaccess` before your `HeaderName` directive:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType text/html .php
```

Neither of the two on their own will do the job. I presume that here Apache (tested on 2.4) first sets a handler and parses the `.php` file, and then agrees to understand that the output type is majorly `text/html` indeed. I'm calling this quirky, but it's working!

Comment: I am on Apache 2;4, could it change anything?

Comment: I'm on 2.4 too, this is working for me. FWIW, have this in my `httpd.conf` in addition to the above (though it shouldn't make a difference on a quick test): `IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort FoldersFirst NameWidth=* XHTML SuppressDescription`.

Comment: Also working fine on Apache 2.2 on my CentOS box. Here's a sampler, cloned my `.htaccess` as the `htaccess.txt` there: http://codesatori.com/tmp/autoindex/ ... (With a custom style sheet from my server defaults in case you're wondering.) Oh and I'm running PHP (7.0.2) as `mod_php` on both local and remote servers, have no idea if running as CGI may change the way this works. I get the impression that `AddHandler` vis-a-vis `AddType` is among the more obscure corners of Apache.

Comment: I set my footer.html to footer.php and it worked... The problem seems to com from my very `header.php` file

Comment: actually it did came from a syntax error in my `header.php` --' I've fixed it now and it works fine, thanks for your suggestions though!

Comment: Syntax errors would definitely pose a problem. ^_^ With my test setup, though, Apache also blurted out the errors into the header/footer. Glad it works.